# i am trying to get an id based on dropdownlist selected item

Tags: asp.net

I have taken a dropdownlist in ajax ModalpopupExtender and fill it from a table then i need to pick up the id of dropdown selected item?

myfile.aspx.cs 
 string MyQuery = string.Format("select Id from table where colName='{0}'", dropdown.SelectedItem.Text);
        SqlConnection con = DatabaseConnection.CreateConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, con);
        string MyId;
        MyId = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

// I also tried this one 
 int id = dropdownList.DataValueField;

please reply me simply how to get id from a table after the select query has executed and when datatable or dataset is filled??? thank you aloooot.

Comment: can you explain Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Is this your original code segment? Table is a keyword, you can't use this way. Other than it seems ok, it should return. tell us what exactly your problem is. Are you getting any error message? Post it.

Answer (score -1):

No this is not my original code segment. when i display the MyId variable in messagebox then it is empty and after insert query it says the insert statement conflicted with foreign key constraints . it means the code does not pick up the id which i need to put in the foreign key in child table.

this is  my code behind file
string MyQuery = string.Format("select DistrictId from District where DistrictName='{0}'", ddlAddDistrict.SelectedItem.Text);
        SqlConnection con = DatabaseConnection.CreateConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, con);
        string MyId;
        MyId = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
        //Response.Write("alert('" + ddlAddDistrict.SelectedItem.Text + "')");
        Response.Write("alert('" + MyId + "')");
        string insert = "insert into PoliceStation values('"+MyId+"','"+policeStation+"')";
        InsertIntoDB.InsertQuery(insert);
        if (InsertIntoDB.count > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("alert('Record added successfully')");
            InsertIntoDB.count = 0;
        }
        else {
            Response.Write("alert('Error: Record does not added')");

```
    }
this is my  .aspx file
```

<%-- ============================Modal popup for police station====================== --%>

```
                <AddNewPopup:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="PanlAddNewPS" TargetControlID="lbtnAddNewPS"
                    CancelControlID="btncanceladdNewPs" BackgroundCssClass="Background" OnLoad="mp1_Load">
                </AddNewPopup:ModalPopupExtender>

                <asp:Panel ID="PanlAddNewPS" runat="server" CssClass="PopupPoliceStation panel-info" align="center" Style="display: none">
                    <%--<a style="width: 600px; height: 200px;" id="irm1" src="PSDialog.aspx" runat="server"></a>--%>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Add New Police Station</div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Add District" Font-Bold="true" ID="Label2" CssClass="col-sm-4 control-label" ></asp:Label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlAddDistrict" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="20" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAddDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

                                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlAddDistrict" ErrorMessage="Select district" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="ValidateAddNewPoliceSation" InitialValue="Select New District"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div> <br /><br />

                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Police Station" Font-Bold="true" ID="lblPSName" CssClass="col-sm-4 control-label" ></asp:Label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddPSName" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddPSName" ErrorMessage="Required" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="ValidateAddNewPoliceSation" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div> <br /><br />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnAddNewPS" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="ValidateAddNewPoliceSation" OnClick="btnAddNewPS_Click" />
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="btncanceladdNewPs" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                </asp:Panel>
```